# What if Google Analytics show UA-3XXXXX-1 ID in Source Code

Tags: javascript, security, google-analytics

I am not from Marketing or Ads side so anyone with expertise. What if Google Analytics show UA-3XXXXX-1 ID in source code? It should be redacted in source code?

If it is in source code how an attacker can take advantage of it? I mean if i have someone code can i inject it in another website and drive fake traffic etc?

Below is this code i am referring to:

```
ga('create', 'UA-3XXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('set', 'userId', 'loginuser'); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 1):

An attacker does not benefit from it, however the data is sent to the defined Analytics property and dirties the real data. This is if the owner of the Property has not properly managed various filters and configurations, in which case the fake data will not have any effect in the reports.

Comment: It mean exposed UA ID will not benefit an attacker in any case?

Comment: Yes, an attacker doesn't get any benefit from it. That ID is always exposed.